# styling a textfield in Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to overide the default style of a textfield compontent in Sencha Touch 2.  I have tried seperate style sheets and I have tried this as well:

```
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        label: 'Blah',
        disabled: true,
        style: 'color:#000 !important',
        value: 'blah blah',
```

How can I change the font color to black for this texfield?

Comment: `Change the font color to black` ? What does that mean? I believe, default font color for textfield is black only. What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

To style your label, add `labelCls` config.

To style your textfield, use selector:

```
input.x-form-field[name="name"]{
  color: your_desired_color;
}
```